# Is there a way to access the old _type metadata on elastic 8.x in script processor?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elastic-stack, data-ingestion

Using Elasticsearch 8.8

Im trying to use script pipeline to reindex documents, i will transform the old _type metadata into a new field '@type', but all scripts remove all _type and _score fields from the source of doc. There is a way to get the string for using to set the new field?

The main goal is a mega upgrade from elastic 2.4 to 8

Doc example:

```
{
  "_index": "foo",
  "_type": "bar",
  "_source": {
  }
}
```

Objective target:

```
{
  "_index": "foo",
  "_source": {
    "@type": "bar"
  }
}
```

Trying something like:
`ctx['@type'] = ctx._type`
Will return "null" because the _type is deleted before running anything. There is a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible as in ES 8 the [reindex context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/8.9/painless-reindex-context.html) doesn't provide that information anymore. It used to be the case [up until 6.8](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-reindex.html) before the removal of mapping types.

What you need to do is to first update your data in your 2.4 source cluster to add that field because 2.4 provide the [`ctx._type` information](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-reindex.html) and only then reindex to 8.9